# How can I create a user specific channel in Pusher?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, pusher

I'm new to `Pusher`. I'm using `Laravel` as my backend. There is a queue job running on the backend, when the user uploads a few photos. What I want to do is to fire an event, that just broadcasts the image objects to pusher and then I receive them via Javascript on the front end and the user gets a notification real-time, saying that all the photos have been uploaded.

At the moment, the channel is created dynamically, based on the user ID and it looks like this:
`user-12-channel`, `12` being the user `id`.

This all works fine, but I'm a bit concerned about the privacy. Someone could easily subscribe to that channel, right?

For example, in my console, when I type pusher.channels (`pusher` being an instance of `Pusher` object), it lists the channels there. What is the workaround to this?

I was looking into the pusher security, and set up a route `/pusher/auth`, which sends back the token, but I don't understand what is that even supposed to do.. from that route, if I send back some dummy text, it still works..

Answer (score 1):

The authorization endpoint is only invoked for private (and by extension, presence) channels. If you want to control access to a channel, it should be named e.g. private-user-12-channel. Then the client will hit your auth endpoint for a token before subscribing, and they will only be able to subscribe if you return them a token signed with your secret.

https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels